# Google Sheets Analytics add-on shows different number of users but same number of sessions

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, sampling, add-on

**Set-up**

I'm using the [Google Sheets Analytics add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) to import my GA data in a Gsheet.

I'm pulling this month's sessions and users via the following simple configuration,

[image]

This works fine, the data is pulled.

---

**Problem**

The `session` number pulled into the Gsheet equals the `session` number displayed in the GA dashboard.

The `user` number, however, differs roughly 10% with the `user` number displayed in the GA dashboard.

I've read some answers remarking differences caused by `sampling`. I'm not entirely sure what that means. Also, those answers were given to people who work directly with the API, not with this Google Sheet add-on. I don't know how to account for this `sampling` in the add-on.

I also don't understand why the `session` number does equal why the `user` number doesn't.

Lastly, I've double checked with data from last month, and the same occurs: `session` number equals and `user` number is about 10% off.

What is going on? How can I ensure the add-on pulls the same user number as displayed in the GA dashboard?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Sampling level` to `LARGE` and that will eliminate any sampling issues. Hopefully your user numbers line up better after that.